# VBA, TRIM part of a Path

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say I have a path : stack/overflow/question/help/please . 
And end result is : help/please.

Does anyone have a code where I can state how many "/" I want to parse.

its similar to text to columns but I would like to keep it in one cell.

Thanks

Comment: You can use fixed width delimitation option.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Do you want a UDF where you give a string `s`, a delimiter `d`, and an integer `i` and it returns the part of the string to the right of the `ith` occurrence of the delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function something like this:

```
Function RightPart(s As String, d As String, n As Long) As String
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, ub As Long
    Dim t As String

    A = Split(s, d)
    ub = UBound(A)
    If n >= ub Then
        RightPart = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = ub - n + 1 To ub
        t = t & A(i) & IIf(i < ub, d, "")
    Next i
   RightPart = t
End Function
```

Then `RightPart(":stack/overflow/question/help/please","/",2)` evaluates to `"help/please"`

Answer (score 2):

you could use this code (does a bit more but should be fine):

```
Public Function custDelim(ByVal str As String, ByVal delim As String, ByVal num As Long) As String
  Dim holder As Variant
  holder = Split(str, delim)
  If num = 0 Then
    custDelim = ""
  ElseIf num > 0 Then
    If num <= UBound(holder) Then
      holder = Split(str, delim, UBound(holder) - num + 2)
      custDelim = holder(UBound(holder))
    Else
      custDelim = str
    End If
  ElseIf num < 0 Then
    If Abs(num) <= UBound(holder) Then
      ReDim Preserve holder(Abs(num) - 1)
      custDelim = Join(holder, delim)
    Else
      custDelim = str
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

`=custDelim("very-long-string-in-here","-",2)` would output "in-here" while using `-2` would print "very-long".

If you still have questions, just ask :)

Comment: The ability to extract from either end is a nice touch.

Comment: It's a leftover from an old function which was going like 'Mid` with start and length for delimeter (using negative numbers to count from back was just easier to use in complex formulas than an extra bool) :P

Answer (score 1):

**[Option 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)** [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)

I prefer using the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) into a variant array when dealing with multiple parts of a string.

```
Function trim_part_of_a_path(str As String, _
                             Optional keep As Integer = 1, _
                             Optional delim As String = "/")
    Dim a As Long, tmp As Variant

    tmp = Split(str, delim)
    If UBound(tmp) < keep Then
        trim_part_of_a_path = str
    Else
        trim_part_of_a_path = tmp(UBound(tmp) - keep)
        For a = UBound(tmp) - keep + 1 To UBound(tmp)
            trim_part_of_a_path = _
                trim_part_of_a_path & delim & tmp(a)
        Next a
    End If
End Function
```

You will likely want to change the defults for the optional parameters to whatever you use most commonly.

> <sup>Syntax:    =**trim_part_of_a_path**(<original string> *, [optional number to retain],  [optional delimiter]*)</sup>
>   <sub>Examples:    =trim_part_of_a_path(A2)
>                     =trim_part_of_a_path(A2, C2, B2)
>                     =trim_part_of_a_path(A2, 1, "/")</sub>

**[Option 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)** [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

The [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) has an optional *[instance_num]* parameter which allows you to change one occurrence of a repeated character to something unique which can be located in subsequent function calculation.

A pair of [LEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56)s with another SUBSTITUTE returns the total number of occurances of a character.

The [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) can use the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) to identify the portion of the original text to return from a modified string produced by the functions discussed above.

[IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can return the original string if the parameters are out of bounds.

```
'return a portion of string while retaining x number of delimiters
=IFERROR(MID(A2, FIND(CHAR(167), SUBSTITUTE(A2, B2, CHAR(167), LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""))-C2))+1, LEN(A2)), A2)
```

A formula based solution probably works best when the parameters can be put into cells that the formula references.

---

### [image: trim_part_of_a_path]