# Excel - Remove beginning in URL list in Excel (pull out unique endings)

Tags: string, excel, url, split, excel-formula

Working from a large list of URLs that all share the same beginning, how can I strip it down to just the unique endings in Excel 2013 or another tool? (ideally with Excel though)

Here are the examples of my initial strings:

http://www.domain.com/sub-folder-name/country/name/page-title-1
http://www.domain.com/sub-folder-name/country2/another-name/different-page-title
http://www.domain.com/sub-folder-name/country3/name3/even-longer-page-title-like-this

I basically want to remove the beginning **http://www.domain.com/sub-folder-name/** from every string in the list - and leave the remainder of the URL, so my list looks like this:

country/name/job-title-1
country2/another-name/different-job-title
country3/name3/even-longer-page-title-like-this

Comment: [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671), [REPLACE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181), [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267EE-9AFA-4639-A02B-F19E1786CF2F) with [LEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56), etc. There are dozens of ways to do this.

Comment: See [VBA, TRIM part of a Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805927/vba-trim-part-of-a-path/35811114#35811114).

Comment: you are looking for something like `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("///",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","///",4)))`???

Comment: @DirkReichel that's exactly it. i think that's one good way to get to what i'm asking for, in this particular use case. i believe your formula looks for content after a certain number of backslashes (4 in our example). i used it to discard the first 4 "levels" of the URL in cell E3 (leaving only the unique ending after the 4th backslash) :


`=RIGHT(E3,LEN(E3)-SEARCH("///",SUBSTITUTE(E3,"/","///",4)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use =RIGHT(url, LEN(url)-number of characters to remove). You can use this formula in a cell, then drag and drop to get your list of unique strings. From there, copy the cells with formulas and paste their values in another column or notepad.

ETA: If you wanted, you could have a cell where you typed in the striung you wanted removed, and then change the formula to =RIGHT(url, LEN(url)-LEN(cell address containing string). That would make the formula more dynamic

Comment: this worked too, thanks! I used it to remove the first 38 characters: 

`=RIGHT(E3, LEN(E3)-38)`